# Enrich logs with custom geoinformation

Tags: logstash

Does anyone know a way to add custom geoip information in Logstash 5.5?

Background:
Logstash 5.x does not support the legacy .dat MaxMind GeoIP databases. There was a tool available to add custom csv data to that database. There is no writer available for the current MMDB format (the only one supported by Logstash 5.x)

I tried with translate and csv filters, but they're not suitable for this task.
Translate can only read one line of csv data and cannot lookup in lines.

A YAML dictionary is also not possible, as I have not only latitude and longitude in my csv but also city names and so on.

It seems a bit strange that there is no plugin to look up data in e.g. a database, csv, whatever and add fields to an object.

Maybe someone has an idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your source data and what is the intended output document?

Comment: There are perl modules for both the legacy format and the MMDB format.  You might be able to use the source code for the .dat version to convert it to the MMDB format.  Also there is a plugin (I wrote) that will do key based lookups in a CSV/YML/JSON file and add multiple fields to an event.  See https://github.com/alcanzar/logstash-filter-augment

Comment: @whites11 My source are nginx and apache access logs which I want to augment with custom geoip data from CSV,JSON,YAML (whatever works best). Output is stored in ElasticSearch.

Comment: @Alcanzar Thanks for the hint, I'll have a look at your plugin.

Comment: @Conrad can you make an example of this custom data? I just don't understand what you are trying to do. If you can, please post an incoming message as you receive it, and the enriched version that you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

In logstash 5.5, you can use the [GeoIP filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-geoip.html) to convert an IP address to a location.

In logstash, you have to configure a filter this way:

```
filter {
    "field": "clientip"
}
```

You need to adjust "clientip" with the field in your document that contains the IP address you want to lookup.

Comment: The geoip filter onlys supports MaxMind's MMDB and not structured files like CSV

Comment: So you don't need a geoip resolution (IP address => latitude/longitude) but some kind of custom mapping (IP address => your value here) ?

Comment: We have a lot of internal users with private ip addresss which are not included in public GeoIP databases. Therefore, I need a solution to look up data related to an IP in a file/database (whatever works).